# How to assign variable values of an array into another variable?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have this function below. The program is supposed to print the storedNumber. However this code `storedNumber = Array[*p][*q];` is a wild guess. Do I need to use `typedef struct`?

```
void selectNumber( char userInput , int *p , int *q , char Array[NROW][NCOL] , char storedNumber )
{
     /* Select the number chosen by the box */
    if ( userInput == 'g' )
         {
            /* Select the number right below the box */
            storedNumber = Array[*p][*q];
            printf( "\n\n%c", storedNumber );
         }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What did it do? Only problem I can see is you assign to storedNumber which is a parameter - either it doesn't need to be a param or else you need to "pass by reference" if you expect it to change outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all your function want to do, you don't need parameter like *p and *q, just p and q is enough, since they won't change in your function.
Also storeNumber is useless parameter, you can just declare one in your function.
Additionally, you should check if p>NROW and q>NCOL to prevent outbound.